# Please explain to me the meaning of these phrases

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I have highlighted the words that I couldn't understand. Please explain to me what they mean.

1 **Put returns** between paragraphs.

2 Butler can be an explosive player, but as a batman struggles under **the more forensic examination** of the longer format.

3 Astros **can't string hits** together in 4-0 loss to Indians or it's tough **to string a couple hits together**

4 **Economical turns of phrase** at his command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. '**Putting returns**': probably means hitting the return key. In other words, start new paragraphs on new lines.
2. '**forensic examination**:' literally 'forensic' is to do with scientific examination of evidence of crime, figuratively it can mean something like 'in thorough detail', which in this instance would mean (I assume here that you are discussing cricket) that the bowling will be thorough enough to find the batsman's weaknesses.
3. '**String hits together**:' means to make several hits in succession, one after another, with no break. The phrase recalls stringing beads together on a thread.
4. '**Economical turn of phrase**:' means the ability to express oneself
   well without wasting words, or without using unnecessarily
   complicated sentence structure.